# Handling events in multiple windows of the same applet

Tags: java, events, applet, jbutton

What is the best way to handle events (enable or disable button) or share parameters across different windows that are opened of the same applet ?
I am not referring to the browser window, instead (run as applet) window in the local IDE.

Which can be the best method to handle this scenario and let the other window know that the event has occurred already and proceed to the next step ? Here, there are no multiple applets. Just one applet, one code base, but multiple instances created.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a model, view, controller system. The model would be the variables under the hood, the view would be the applet, and the controller would be the buttons and other interactions. Many of the Swing components take a variable(model) in the constructor and automatically update with that. If you want to alert a specific function that a variable has been changed by any button, use property change listeners.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Comment: I agree with PropertyChangeListeners, to reflect and update the latest values. But this occurs in the current focussed window. If for example there are 2 windows of the same applet open, the one that the user currently has focus, updates with the new values. I would like to pass the same new value, to the other applet window, which is out of focus as well. I do not see Property change listeners being of help to achieve this task.